# How many siblings does Tonnura have?

Tags: tonnura-san

From chapter 7 we know that Tonnura and Duke are brothers:

[image]

The next chapter, though, implies that Duke may not be Tonnura's only sibling.

[image]

Has it been revealed how many other siblings Tonnura has? And do we know anything about them (in particular, are they all large talking cats like Tonnura)?

Comment: I don't know the manga at all so I have have no idea about an in-canon answer, but I do know that brethren doesn't always mean brothers in a literal sense. It can also just be members of the same group/nationality/etc. So he could mean it in that way.

Comment: @kuwaly While you are correct about the meaning of the term "brethren", it is clear in this context that they are using the term to refer to siblings. Here's another panel from chapter 8 which makes this more explicit: http://i.imgur.com/hPg1FZ9.png

Comment: Makes sense. I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Tonnura is one of 7 siblings, but only 4 have been revealed as of volume 7 of the manga. They are:

Tonnura, the titular character (and elderest brother)

[image: ;3]

Duke, the younger brother

[image: this one's pretty epic!]

Charmy, the youngest sister

[image: how charming]

Donsuke, the youngest brother

[image: he's a big one]